# Problema con librería Faust

Tags: python, queue

Tengo un código Python que hace uso de la librería Faust para consumir datos de un tópico de Kafka. El código es el siguiente:

```
from conf.kafka_conf import *
import faust
import asyncio
# Configuración sencilla de Faust utilizando la configuración importada
app = faust.App(
    CONSUMER,
    broker=BROKER_URL, 
    value_serializer=FORMAT,
)
topic = app.topic(TOPIC)

@app.agent(topic)
async def consume_messages(messages):
    try:
        async for message in messages:
            data = message
            #processData(data)
            print(f'Received message: {data}')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Los datos de conexión se reciben de un archivo externo, y son correctos y llegan bien, eso ya lo he comprobado.
Intento poner en marcha el código con `faust -A main worker`. Obtengo el siguiente error:

```
┌ƒaµS† v1.10.4┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ id          │ kafka://localhost:29092                                                      │
│ transport   │ [URL('kafka://my-kafka-consumer')]                                           │
│ store       │ memory:                                                                      │
│ web         │ http://macbook-pro-de-jose.local:6066                                        │
│ log         │ -stderr- (warn)                                                              │
│ pid         │ 4844                                                                         │
│ hostname    │ MacBook-Pro-de-Jose.local                                                    │
│ platform    │ CPython 3.11.2 (Darwin x86_64)                                               │
│ drivers     │                                                                              │
│   transport │ aiokafka=1.1.6                                                               │
│   web       │ aiohttp=3.8.5                                                                │
│ datadir     │ /Users/chefito/Desktop/CURSO_IA/data_engineer/kafka:/localhost:29092-data    │
│ appdir      │ /Users/chefito/Desktop/CURSO_IA/data_engineer/kafka:/localhost:29092-data/v1 │
└─────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
starting➢  [2023-09-26 09:27:17,159] [4844] [ERROR] [^Worker]: Error: TypeError("Queue.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'loop'") 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chefito/Desktop/CURSO_IA/data_engineer/de_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mode/worker.py", line 273, in execute_from_commandline
    self.loop.run_until_complete(self._starting_fut)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/chefito/Desktop/CURSO_IA/data_engineer/de_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mode/services.py", line 736, in start
    await self._default_start()
  File "/Users/chefito/Desktop/CURSO_IA/data_engineer/de_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mode/services.py", line 743, in _default_start
    await self._actually_start()
  File "/Users/chefito/Desktop/CURSO_IA/data_engineer/de_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mode/services.py", line 767, in _actually_start
    await child.maybe_start()
  File "/Users/chefito/Desktop/CURSO_IA/data_engineer/de_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mode/services.py", line 795, in maybe_start
    await self.start()
  File "/Users/chefito/Desktop/CURSO_IA/data_engineer/de_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mode/services.py", line 736, in start
    await self._default_start()
  File "/Users/chefito/Desktop/CURSO_IA/data_engineer/de_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mode/services.py", line 743, in _default_start
    await self._actually_start()
  File "/Users/chefito/Desktop/CURSO_IA/data_engineer/de_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mode/services.py", line 749, in _actually_start
    for dep in self.on_init_dependencies():
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/chefito/Desktop/CURSO_IA/data_engineer/de_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/faust/app/base.py", line 567, in on_init_dependencies
    return self.boot_strategy.server()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/chefito/Desktop/CURSO_IA/data_engineer/de_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/faust/app/base.py", line 277, in server
    self.kafka_consumer(),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/chefito/Desktop/CURSO_IA/data_engineer/de_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/faust/app/base.py", line 328, in kafka_consumer
    self.app.consumer,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/chefito/Desktop/CURSO_IA/data_engineer/de_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/faust/app/base.py", line 1818, in consumer
    self._consumer = self._new_consumer()
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/chefito/Desktop/CURSO_IA/data_engineer/de_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/faust/app/base.py", line 1674, in _new_consumer
    return self.transport.create_consumer(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/chefito/Desktop/CURSO_IA/data_engineer/de_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/faust/transport/base.py", line 68, in create_consumer
    return self.Consumer(self, callback=callback,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/chefito/Desktop/CURSO_IA/data_engineer/de_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/faust/transport/consumer.py", line 1231, in __init__
    self._method_queue = MethodQueue(loop=self.loop, beacon=self.beacon)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/chefito/Desktop/CURSO_IA/data_engineer/de_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mode/threads.py", line 331, in __init__
    self._queue = asyncio.Queue(loop=self.loop)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Queue.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'loop'
 stopping         %
```

Tengo Python 3.11.2 y Faust 1.10.4 en un MacBook Pro con chip Intel.

¿Alguien sabe a que se debe?

Answer (score 0):

*¿Cómo puedes estar usando Faust 1.10.4 si la última versión es la 0.10.16? Voy a suponer que estás en la 0.10.4*

---

Faust usaba el módulo **mode** que ha dejado de tener mantenimiento desde hace unos años.

Aquí hay algunos tickets pendientes sobre este problema:

https://github.com/ask/mode/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+queue+loop

Por este motivo, los desarrolladores de Faust han decidido crear su propio *fork* de **mode**:

https://github.com/faust-streaming/mode/

Que lo puedes instalar como:

`pip install mode-streaming`

Pero asegúrate de haber desintalado el **mode** original:

`pip uninstall mode`

Nota: a partir de Faust 0.4.0 se cambió la dependencia del módulo `mode` a módulo `mode-streaming`. Si tenías instalador Faust 0.10.4 entonces se debería haber instalado `mode-streaming` automáticamente.

Espero que funcione. Yo no lo he probado.

Comment: Yo he puesto en la terminal faust --version y me devuelve faust, version Faust 1.10.4. y en pypi.org es la versión de faust desde febrero de 2020 (https://pypi.org/search/?q=faust)

Comment: Desafortunadamente esto no soluciona el problema, pero gracias.

Comment: Esa versión está anticuada tal como [comentan en github](https://github.com/robinhood/faust#deprecation-notice). Utiliza la versión nueva (faust-streaming 0.10.16) que está en <https://github.com/faust-streaming/faust>

Answer (score 0):

Faust has transitioned away from the now-discontinued 'mode' module, and there are some outstanding issues related to this change:

You can find the open issues here: [link to GitHub issues]

In response, the Faust developers have taken the initiative to create their own fork of the 'mode' module:

You can access it here: [link to Faust's 'mode' fork on GitHub]

To use this new 'mode-streaming' module, simply install it with pip:

pip install mode-streaming
Please ensure that you have uninstalled the original 'mode' module:

pip uninstall mode
It's important to note that starting from Faust 0.4.0, the module dependency has shifted from 'modeto' to 'mode-streaming'. If you had Faust 0.10.4 installed, 'mode-streaming' should have been automatically included.

While I haven't personally tested this, I hope this information proves helpful. read this blog for more info [yes ai mod apk](https://modlonely.com/yesai-mod-apk/)

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! Las respuestas y preguntas deben estar en el idioma del sitio.